# Abstract base class within abstract base class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a an abstract base class `FooBase` that's inherited by `Foo`.  And I have another abstract base class `BarBase` that's inherited by `Bar`.  `BarBase` contains an abstract `FooBase` property.  And in `Bar` I want to set the `FooBase` property to `Foo`.  Why is this not allowed?  Is this a crazy design that needs to be rethought, or can it be done in some way?

```
public abstract class FooBase
{
}

public class Foo : FooBase
{
}

public abstract class BarBase
{
    public abstract FooBase Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : BarBase
{
    public override Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Use generics, just like Patrick's answer demonstrates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can't change the signature when overriding. Period. That is how C# was designed. A better solution here would be using generics:

```
public abstract class FooBase
{
}

public class Foo : FooBase
{
}

public abstract class BarBase<F> where F : FooBase
{
    public F Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : BarBase<Foo>
{
}
```